# How to check the order of Pole by derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I know the basics of the poles and the residues. However I am stuck at a point. I am trying to understand the fact that for the following integral

$\int_{\gamma R} \dfrac{(e^{az})}{ (1+e^z)} dz $

Where $\gamma R$ is a closed curve formed by the points $R,-R,R+2i\pi , -R+2i\pi$, has simple pole at $z=i\pi$.

The step that was done for proving the pole is simple, was as below...

Since $(1+{e^{z}})'=e^{z} \neq 0$ for $z=i\pi$ hence th pole is a simple pole.

I didn't read any definition of this type. Will anybody please explain?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point $z$ is called a pole of $f(z)$ if it is a zero of some order $m$ of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$.

So here if $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{z}}$ then what is the order of the zero of $1+e^{z}$ at $z=i\pi$ ?.

Well say it is of order $m$.

Then $\frac{1}{f(z)}=(z-i\pi)^{m}g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is a holomorphic function which is non zero at $z=i\pi$.

Then $1+e^{z}=(z-i\pi)^{m}g(z)$.

Differentiatiing :-

$e^{z}=m(z-i\pi)^{m-1}g(z)+(z-i\pi)^{m}g'(z)$

But if you plug in $z=i\pi$ the right hand side is non-zero but the left hand side is zero for $m\geq 2$.
So the order $m$ must be $1$.

Hence they are concluding so.

So you have $i\pi$ is a simple pole.

Comment: Ohh, so it means if $f(z)= \dfrac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ has a singularity at $z_0$ then for the denominator $h(z)$, we take the derivatives, if the derivative $h^{(n)}(z_0) \neq 0$ , for smallest $n$, then will we say that the pole is of order $n$?

Comment: Yeah you can think of it like that.  its the same analogy as that with roots of a polynomial. For example, we say that $a$ is a root of $f(x)$ of order $n$ if $f^{k}(a)=0$ for $1\leq k\leq n-1$ and $f^{n}(a)$ is non-zero. Basically you can ignore $g(z)$  as long as it is holomorphic and just focus on the denominator and the order of zero it has.

Comment: Okay... Thank You for your explanations...